# what is it called when your fingers turn in shape after being under water for a long period

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Have you ever noticed when you are under water for a long time, your finger tips turn white and their skin is not as smooth as before and they change. But after a while they go back to their previous shape. I wanna know how to refer to that shape of skin. Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: AS kids, we called them *chicken fingers* (which now has a whole new meaning).

Comment: Grandma hands..

Comment: I have no idea what the scientific name for it is but my dad says my fingers go 'geshrimfeld' whenever that happens.

Comment: Aquadigeous leaching.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most people would call that sort of thing *wrinkled* or maybe *pruned*, perhaps even *corrugated* if they were particularly prone to long words.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrinkle#Water-immersion_wrinkling) writes:

> The wrinkles that occur in skin after prolonged exposure to water are sometimes referred to as *pruney fingers* or water aging. This is a temporary skin condition where the skin on the palms of the hand or feet becomes wrinkly. This wrinkling response may have imparted an evolutionary benefit by providing improved traction in wet conditions, and a better grasp of wet objects.

Comment: In addition to _pruned fingers_ (as tchrist says) and _pruney fingers_ (as Wikipedia says), another common variant is simply _prune fingers_.

Comment: I'm not sure I would want [pruned](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prune-2) fingers! "Turned into the likeness of a prune" is not the first meaning of *pruned* which occurred to me.

Comment: Would *pruned* in that case necessarily mean "having the likeness of a prune" would could it be understood as "cut down" or "shortened", in the way you prune a tree?

Comment: I have never heard *corrugated* myself and probably would never use it. Unlike *wrinkled* and *pruned*, I don't think it's a common idiom.

Comment: **Feet** turn pruney too ([livescience.com](http://www.livescience.com/26097-why-fingers-pruney-water.html))

Answer (score 13):

It's called (water immersion) [wrinkling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrinkle#Water-immersion_wrinkling).

Comment: I spent a few minutes looking for the standard dermatological description and, surprisingly, it appears to be "water immersion wrinkling." as Ilmari Karonen rightly suggests.  Usually, you can count on the dermatologists for nice, long latinized description.  A related term, "paddy-field foot," describes changes in the foot when it has been immersed in warm water for a couple of days or so.